# Google Ads Preview BigQuery Data Transer

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

There are no matching costs between Google Ads Preview Data Transfer's tables - ads_GeoStats and ads_CampaignStats.

I'm interested in getting matched locations cost report for our world campaigns and I used  ads_GeoStats table for that but when I check the value of metrics_cost_micros in ads_GeoStats, it shows that it is less than the value of metrics_cost_micros in ads_CampaignStats or Google Ads console.

Steps to reproduce:

select sum(metrics_cost_micros/1000000) from `a.google_ads_preview.ads_CampaignStats_*`
where campaign_id = 123
and _DATA_DATE ='YYYY-MM-DD'

select sum(metrics_cost_micros/1000000) from `a.google_ads_preview.ads_GeoStats_*`
where campaign_id =123
and _DATA_DATE = 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Any help in understanding why this gap exists?

Thanks,
Roy

Expect the same costs from the google ads console and ads_GeoStats table.